# Does express serve static files from hidden (dot) folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My app is serving a static folder like this

```
app.use('/static', serveStatic(__dirname + '/view/my/static/folder'));
```

How to configure server to serve a hidden folder? So if i have

```
/view/my/static/folder/.hidden/some-text.txt
```

I would like to see this on

localhost:8080/static/.hidden/some-text.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue happened due to my stupidity. Nodemon did not catch that i added a .folder and did not restart server (which I did not notice). When I restarted it manually everything worked like expected

Answer (score 17):

I found this question from googling after I couldn't serve hidden *files*.  I discovered that express doesn't serve them by default.

You can serve them with the [`dotfiles`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#dotfiles) option:

```
app.use(express.static( __dirname+'/static', {dotfiles:'allow'} ));
```

[source](https://evanhahn.com/express-dot-static-deep-dive/)

Comment: Hm I actually did not try with hidden files, but with files served from .folder/ 

Your answer might help someone :) thanks

Comment: The [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.static) say `Determines how dotfiles (files or directories that begin with a dot “.”) are treated`, so it should work for folders too.

Comment: You are right. However note this - "With the default value, it will *not* ignore files in a directory that begins with a dot.".  So dotfiles are ignored, but files in dot folders are not ignored by default. Weird default setup if you ask me.