# download file starting with period

Tags: javascript, download

I have code to create a download link for dynamicly created data.  It works except that I want the filename to be .env I can download a file called env or config.env but not plain .env is this a browser restriction?

```
function fileDownload(data: string, fileName: string, mimeType: string) {
    const dataStr = `data:${mimeType};charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(
        data
    )}`;
    const downloadAnchorNode = document.createElement('a');

    downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute('href', dataStr);
    downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    document.body.appendChild(downloadAnchorNode); // required for firefox
    downloadAnchorNode.click();
    downloadAnchorNode.remove();
}

export function plainFileDownload(data: string, fileName: string) {
    fileDownload(data, fileName, 'application/x-empty');
}

textFileDownload('some dynamic text', '.env');  // Called on button click
```

Comment: Q: Add some error handling to determine exactly where the failure is occurring.  My guess is that "dot env" is a ["hidden file"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory).

Answer (score 0):

Whether the access to dot files is restricted or not really depends on your server config.

It is unclear from the question what is your server config or even what you use on server-side.

In my experience most of the tools/frameworks **will not** serve files/folders prefixed with a dot by default (for instance, express & Apache will not) however you can configure them to do so:

- [Check this if you use Express](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43383312/9430588)
- [Check this if you use Apache](https://serverfault.com/q/245922)

Be sure that you know what you are doing. Dot-prefixed file are hidden by default because they tend to contain some sensitive information that you normally wouldn't like to share with everyone.